# setup.py requires pkg to either not exist or exist in specific version

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a package I'm writing (**A**). Some of the functionality in it depends on another package (**B**), but most of it doesn't, so I don't require **A** to install **B**. Only when a specific method is called, I issue a warning "please install **B**" (I think I saw this behavior in packages like `pandas`, or `plotly`)

My issue is that when using **B**, I want it to be in specific versions. Is it possible to enforce it inside `setup.py`?

1. This would enforce installation of B, which I don't want

```
setup(
    name='A',
    install_requires=['B>=1'],   
)
```

2. I thought of something along the lines of this:

```
setup(
    name='A',
    install_requires=['B!=0.1 !=0.2 ...'],   
)
```

but I think there isn't a built in way in `setuptools` for that. Is there a good way to do this? Should I even do that or just skip checking for **B** during install time at all?